# Update different columns on multiple rows in a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have the following table:

```
id | col_a | col_b | col_c
1  |   abc |  null |  qwqw
2  |  null |  null |  null
3  |  null |  ijij |  cba
```

And we want to do the following updates:

- row 1: SET col_a = cba
- row 2: SET col_b = uiui, col_c = zxzx
- row 3: SET col_b = null

First, is it possible to do it in one query?

If not, what's the best alternative?

- One query per row, like UPDATE table SET ... WHERE id=1;
- Fetch the rows, replace the old values with the new values, and do a massive INSERT INTO table VALUES ... ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET col_a = EXCLUDED.col_a, col_b = EXCLUDED.col_b, col_c = EXCLUDED.col_c;
- Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is three `updates`:

```
update t
    set col_a = cba
    where id = 1;

update t
    set col_b = uiui, col_c = zxzx
    where id = 2;

update t
    set col_b = null
    where id = 3;
```

You can wrap these in a transaction so they take effect at the same time.  Assuming you have an index on `id`, this should have good performance.

You can put these into a single statement using conditional logic:

```
update t
    set col_a = (case when id = 1 then cba else col_a end),
        col_b = (case when id = 2 then uiui 
                      when id = 3 then null
                      else col_b
                 end),
        col_c = (case when id = 2 then zxzx else col_c end)
    where id in (1, 2, 3);
```

I think three separate statements is clearer and less prone to error.

Comment: Thanks for the single statement. That's what I was looking for. Do you think it has any performance advantage other 3 separate queries? Here I asked my question with only 3 updates to make it simple, but in the real situation I will have many more updates, and very frequently, so I am looking for any possible performance improvement.

Comment: @leyou . . . If the `where` conditions use an index, then separate updates in a single transaction should give reasonable performance.  The `on conflict` method is clever and should also work.  If you are updating a significant proportion of rows in the table, then truncate and re-insert might be the fastest approach.

Comment: I made some quick tests on my laptop by simulating 10,000 random row updates. Using one query per row update it took around 12 seconds. Using "select + insert on conflict" it took around 6 seconds. And using the single statement, it took around 5 seconds.

Comment: @leyou . . . When you did one query per row, did you use a single transaction for three updates or  a separate transaction per update?

Comment: My bad, I did not. Did it again with a single transaction for three updates, and it now takes about 8 seconds for "one query per update". Here is the code I use to do the tests: https://pastebin.com/XGjjQRhH